# How Does The Maybe Monad Relate To The Option Type?

Tags: functional-programming, monad

I was doing a presentation on F# and was discussing the Option type when someone in the audience asked me if the Option type is F#'s implementation of the maybe monad.  I know that's not the case but I did want to ask how the two concepts are related.  I mean it seems to me that an option type might be the result of the operation of a maybe monad but I'm not even sure of that.

Would someone elucidate the relationship between the maybe monad and the option type in those functional languages which support it?

Comment: Just curious, but how do you know `that's not the case`?  They look very similar to me.

Comment: That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading the documentation on F#'s `Option` type, it looks like it does behave pretty much exactly like the `Maybe` type in Haskell, in that it can model either 'nothing' (`None` in F#, `Nothing` in Haskell), or a value of its argument type (`Some` in F#, `Just` in Haskell).

In Haskell, however, `Maybe` is also a monad, and the plumbing is such that it allows for calculations on `Maybe` values, early-returning `Nothing` if any of the variables in the calculation is `Nothing`. Used this way, `Maybe` is a simple error handler (or rather, error-ignoring device), and the fact that it is a monad allows moving the boilerplate out of the way. Look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad) for a nice concise example. I don't think `Option` supports this kind of monadic usage (in fact, I'm wondering whether there is any explicit concept of a monad in F# at all). If you want this behavior in .NET, I guess you'd use `Option.Value` for all your arguments, and wrap the whole calculation in a try / catch on `NullReferenceException`.

So, while `Option` is similar to the `Maybe` **type**, it is not an equivalent to the `Maybe` **monad**.

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation.  Frankly I always considered they weren't the same (one's a type the other's a monad) but I wasn't altogether clear on how one related to the other.

Comment: BTW--there is a monad type of concept in F#; it's called a computation expression.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: Ah, OK. I haven't had an awful lot of F# exposure, so excuse me. Anyway, in Haskell, monads *are* types, more specifically, types of the `Monad` typeclass. `Maybe` is a plain old data type, but it also happens to implement `Monad` to provide this 'special' behavior.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that technically speaking, a monad isn't so much a type as it is a mathematical structure. The option type has a valid type contructor (`Some(val : a) : a option`) and it'd be trivial to write a `bind` implementation for it (if it doesn't already exist in the option module in F# which wouldn't surprise me). The `Monad` typeclass in haskell isn't what magically turns something into a monad, it's just a syntactic way of telling the compiler about the interface of the `Maybe` (for instance) type. This allows for *polymorphism* over monads, it doesn't allow monads per se.

Comment: in short: I don't at all agree that they're not equivalent. language constructs like type classes or polymorphism doesn't change a types fundamental mathematical properties and structure.

Comment: F#'s Option's `map` and `bind` functions behave identically to Haskell's Maybe's `fmap` and `bind` functions. They are both monads and have equivalent monadic behavior. Haskell just has a `Monad` typeclass that lets you manipulate monads, while in F# they're more like an abstract "design pattern".

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they're equivalent in the sense that the `Option` type together with `Option.bind` and type constructor `Some` constitute a monad.

While monads (as in the `Monad` typeclass) are a central part of Haskells identity, from a conceptual point of view they're a language-agnostic construct. A design pattern if you like. If you have a type, and you have a bind and a return function with specific signatures that obey a particular set of laws - you have a monad - regardless of the language you use.

F# computation expressions only provide a programmable syntax sugar for monads, similar to the do notation in Haskell. While there's no `Option` computation expression builder provided out of the box, you can easily define a bare-bones one like this:

```
type OptionBuilder () = 
    member this.Bind(m, f) = Option.bind f m
    member this.Return(a) = Some a 

let option = OptionBuilder ()
```

And use it like this:

```
let c = 
    option {
        let! a = Some 4
        let! b = None
        return a + b
    }
```

which is a sugared equivalent of something like this:

```
let c =
    (Some 4) 
    |> Option.bind (fun a ->
        None 
        |> Option.bind (fun b ->
             Some (a + b)))
```

Note how the builder members mirror the `Monad` typeclass, and how you can write monadic - even if convoluted - code without a builder.

Answer (score 3):

They're equivalent, and they're both monads. The difference is being a monad *means* something in Haskell - there's an explicit `Monad` typeclass and "do notation" can be used to eliminate a lot of boilerplate when writing monadic code. In F#, builder notation and `let!` and `do!` can be used to get rid of similar boilerplate, but there is *not* an explicit notion of a type "being a monad". Haskell's type system includes typeclasses (of which the general `Monad` class is) and higher kinded types (of which an individual `Monad` is), which allow writing code that works for all monads. F#'s type system has neither of these features.

So yes, F#'s `Option` and Haskell's `Maybe` are identical and both monads. It's just that Haskell gives you a lot more machinery to work with monads than F# does.